# Check whether or not a point is in a polygon (Google Maps API)

Tags: api, google-maps, polygon, point-in-polygon

So I have a map [here](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/ms?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Hemel+Hempstead,+Hertfordshire,+United+Kingdom&msa=0&msid=102452963384592422653.000492a9490b4721eceb8&ll=52.148659,0.00824&spn=0.672442,1.972046&z=9&iwloc=000492a94ca48a5d82414)

How can I, using Google Maps API, detect whether or not a given coordinate is within that polygon? Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. See this function: http://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon

Answer (score 1):

Google provides one already

```
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(25.774, -80.190),
      new google.maps.LatLng(18.466, -66.118),
      new google.maps.LatLng(32.321, -64.757)
    ]
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, bermudaTriangle));
  });
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#containsLocation